# Chi.URLParam gives errorpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: rest, go, crud

Endpoint URL i am trying to get id value from URL, everytime I want to get value it gets no value, When I tried to convert the received input from URL it shows nothing

```
router.Get("/employees/getone/{id}", h.GetOne)
```

Handler

```
func GetOne(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id := chi.URLParam(r, "id")
    ID, err := strconv.Atoi(id)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error", err)
        //return
    }
    fmt.Println("id is :", id)
    slc := data.GetOneEmp(ID)
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(slc, "", "   ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Write(out)
}
```

Database operation

```
func GetOneEmp(id int) []m.Employees {
    rows, err := d.DB.Query(`SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$1`, id)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var item m.Employees
    var slc []m.Employees
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(&item.ID, &item.Name, &item.Rank, &item.Address, &item.Salary)
        //show status as well
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            //return everywhere when you get an error
        }
        slc = append(slc, item)
    }
    return slc
}
```

Comment: @icza - Can you please help

Comment: It is very unlikely that the panic is caused by `chi.URLParam`. It's probably some other code. The panic's stacktrace will point you directly to the file and line of the offending code. If you don't know how to read the stacktrace you should include it in the question, in full.

Comment: Note also that you are not handling errors properly. This is quite irresponsible. Don't just print-and-continue-like-nothing-happened in case of errors. Instead you should exit, or fallback, or whatever, but NOT continue like nothing happened.

Comment: @mkopriva - please suggest how to handle errors - I am a beginner in software development and golang.

Comment: pq: invalid input syntax for type integer: "" gives me this error

Comment: when i print id, i get nothing

Comment: That error suggests that `id` is an empty string, not `int`, and you passed that to `d.DB.Query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$1", id)`. This also suggests that the code you are executing is different from the code in the question.

Comment: Please consider reading, and adhering to, "[mcve]".

Comment: @mkopriva - actually i was trying to get id value from the URL with the help of chi.URLParam which I have assigned to id value, after getting id value from value i want to perform database operation with id value,so i was sending id value to  d.DB.Query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=$1", id)

Comment: when i convert the id value to an integer, i get results associated with id =0 value